# Hamcrest Matchers contains with List of matchers

Tags: java, list, contains, matcher, hamcrest

I am trying to use [org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains(java.util.List<Matcher<? super E>>)](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(java.util.List)), but the compiler tells me that it cannot resolve the method.

I even tried the example given by Hamcrest [here](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(java.util.List)), but I get the same compilation error:

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), contains(Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))));

Error:(13, 9) java: no suitable method found for assertThat(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.util.List<org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>>>>)
method org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.<T>assertThat(T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super T>) is not applicable
  (actual argument org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.util.List<org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>>>> cannot be converted to org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super java.util.List<java.lang.String>> by method invocation conversion)
method org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.<T>assertThat(java.lang.String,T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super T>) is not applicable
  (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(java.lang.String,boolean) is not applicable
  (actual argument java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation conversion)
```

I tried to cast the second argument to Matcher<? super List<String>>

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), (Matcher<? super List<String>>)contains(Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))));
```

but then I get another compilation error:

```
Error:(16, 88) java: inconvertible types  
required: org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super java.util.List<java.lang.String>> 
found:    org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.util.List<org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>>>>
```

Is there a way to properly use this method?

Comment: That matcher checks that the list contains some element, but you're passing in list of matchers. `Arrays.asList("foo, "bar")` is a `List<String>`, so it's not going to contain `asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))`. What are you trying to test?

Comment: Please read the Javadoc for the method (see link provided in question).
The Matchers.contains(List<Matcher>) should verify that each item from the first argument satisfies the corresponding matcher from the second argument.

Comment: `assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), contains(Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))));` works; have you go some odd static imports for contains or equalTo?

Comment: The imports look ok to me:
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"));` will give you the type `List<Matcher<String>>`, but you really want `List<Matcher<? super String>>`. You have to explicitly specify the type:

```
assertThat(str, 
    contains(Arrays.<Matcher<? super String>>asList(
        equalTo("foo"), 
        equalTo("bar"))));
```