# How use matchers for collection with Hamcrest?

Tags: java, generics, junit, matcher, hamcrest

The input:

1. Collection with MyElement **without** equals method.
2. A org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher implementation, which matches element by some field.

The goal is make following statement compilable:

```
Collection<MyElement> elements = ...
Collection<TypeSafeMatchert> matchers = ...
assertThat(elements, Matchers.contains(matchers); //<error here
```

What have to use here? It wants me to `Matcher<? super java.util.List<MyElement>>` and told that actully I passed `Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? super java.util.List<MyElement>>>`. So how to pass a Matcher Collection here?

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624592/hamcrest-compare-collections) about comparing collections with hamcrest, but there is no example with passing Matchers collection, not elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hamcrest compare collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624592/hamcrest-compare-collections)

Comment: very close, but there no answer with use Matcher instead of elements. :(

Comment: try specifying types; like there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103222/hamcrest-matchers-contains-with-list-of-matchers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a `Collection` of `TypeSafeMatchers`, you need to define a:

```
    List<Matcher<? super MyElement>> matchers = ...;
```

This way, `Hamcrest` will know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use List instead of collection for the matchers, or convert it to array.

Hamcrest has following `contains` methods:

```
public static <E> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> contains(org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super E>... itemMatchers)

public static <E> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> contains(E... items)

public static <E> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> contains(org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super E> itemMatcher)

public static <E> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> contains(java.util.List<org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super E>> itemMatchers)
```

As you can see it handles Matchers only in case of a `List` or varags (but if you pass only one element then you need to convert it to array).